# Though i'm performing Inorder Traversal for my Binary Tree, why it's displaying my Right sub Tree first?

Tags: java, binary-tree, inorder

**I was performing in_order traversal for my binary tree,Instead of displaying my left sub tree first,it's displaying my right sub tree.
Please find my bug.**

//Inserting

```
public void Insert(int data)
{
    Node temp=new Node(data);
    
    if(root==null) root=temp;
    else
    {
        Node traverse=root;
        Node parent=root;
        
        while( traverse!=null )
        {
            parent=traverse;
            if(traverse.Data > temp.Data) traverse=traverse.Right;
            else traverse=traverse.Left;
        }
        
        if( parent.Data > temp.Data ) parent.Right=temp;
        else parent.Left=temp;
        
    }
}
```

//Inorder Traversal

```
public void display(Node traverse)
{
    if(traverse != null)
    {
        display(traverse.Left);
        System.out.print(traverse.Data+"->");
        display(traverse.Right);
    }
}
```

[My_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyoHi.png)

Output should be: 12->15->18->20->22->25->30

[Main Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0XCj.png)

[Node Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7666M.png)

Comment: If you want us to help you find your bug, you should give a complete example that we can run. Currently you are neither telling us how you insert the data nor what methods you call to actually get the output you claim to get. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Edit: You now added some code, but you should have done so as formatted text that people can copy and not as a screenshot.

Comment: Also don't post images of code, paste it. Read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) why.

Answer (score 0):

In `insert` there is an issue in this code:

```
            if(traverse.Data > temp.Data) traverse=traverse.Right;
            else traverse=traverse.Left;
```

As `temp` holds the data you want to insert, you are here storing *lesser* values in the *right* subtree of a node (`traverse`). It should be the opposite.

The same mistake occurs after the loop, in this code:

```
    if( parent.Data > temp.Data ) parent.Right=temp;
    else parent.Left=temp;
```